# How to delete null values for group?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working with an address file that contains the unit number and address. I want to delete instances where an address has multiple units (of which one entry at minimum include a non-blank value for the unit number) **and** a null value.

The unit number can be formatted in many ways, including "Unit 1", a numeric digit ("1"), and a letter ("A").

I am looking for a solution using `dplyr`.

**Input:**

```
library(dplyr)
test <- tibble(Unit = c(NA, "Unit 1", "Unit 2", "Unit 3", NA, NA, "Unit TH1"), Address = c("123 Fake Street", "123 Fake Street", "123 Fake Street", "123 Fake Street", "456 Fake Street", "456 Fake Street", "789 Fake Street"))

# A tibble: 7 × 2
  Unit   Address        
  <chr>  <chr>          
1 NA     123 Fake Street
2 Unit 1 123 Fake Street
3 Unit 2 123 Fake Street
4 Unit 3 123 Fake Street
5 NA     456 Fake Street
6 NA     456 Fake Street
7 Unit TH1 789 Fake Street
```

**Desired Output:**

```
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  Unit   Address             
  <chr>  <chr>          
1 Unit 1 123 Fake Street
2 Unit 2 123 Fake Street
3 Unit 3 123 Fake Street
4 NA     456 Fake Street
5 NA     456 Fake Street
6 Unit TH1 789 Fake Street
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `group_by` the `Address` column first, then `filter` according to your requirement (more than 1 `Unit` **AND** contains `NA`, note the negation `!`, or `all` of the `Unit` are `NA`).

```
library(dplyr)

test %>% 
  group_by(Address) %>% 
  filter(!(n() > 1 & is.na(Unit)) | all(is.na(Unit))) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 6 × 2
  Unit     Address        
  <chr>    <chr>          
1 Unit 1   123 Fake Street
2 Unit 2   123 Fake Street
3 Unit 3   123 Fake Street
4 NA       456 Fake Street
5 NA       456 Fake Street
6 Unit TH1 789 Fake Street
```

#### Data

```
test <-
  tibble(
    Unit = c(NA, "Unit 1", "Unit 2", "Unit 3", NA, NA, "Unit TH1"),
    Address = c(
      "123 Fake Street",
      "123 Fake Street",
      "123 Fake Street",
      "123 Fake Street",
      "456 Fake Street",
      "456 Fake Street",
      "789 Fake Street"
    )
  )
```

Comment: I've made an update to my original post following your suggestion. I have address entries where there is no unit number at all in the dataframe ("456 Fake Street" in my example), but I want to keep these entries.

Comment: @VancityPlanner I totally missed your reply. You can add `| all(is.na(Unit))` in the `filter` to keep `Address` that are all `NA` in the `Unit` column.